html tags do not apply in react tsx props
I have a code as following and when I want to bold a word I have no idea why html does not apply to it in my tsx file
   <myComponent
   contents={`<strong>example</strong> `}
    >

I have tried using example as well but all the html tags get displayed on webpage as I type them. what would be the solution?

First tip is to use ChatGPT for this, it would save you time. But since you asked it looks like you’re passing down props as a string instead of a component. Try removing the backticks

When you pass HTML as a string wrapped in backticks (``), it gets treated as plain text. React doesn't automatically interpret strings as HTML, which is why your <strong> gets displayed as text.
Solution
Instead of passing the HTML as a string, pass it directly as JSX.
import { ReactNode } from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ contents }: { contents: ReactNode }) => {
  return <div>{contents}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return <MyComponent contents={<strong>example</strong>} />;
}

